# Is it possible to look for element by it's CSS using text contains?

Tags: python, selenium

Couldn't find the answer. As normal xpath has Contains(text(), 'text'), I cannot obtain the same within css selector.

```
By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.class::contains('text')"
```

Is there any other way to do it  ?

Comment: Explain what you are trying to achieve. Do you have a full code?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into sub-string matches [here](https://saucelabs.com/resources/articles/selenium-tips-css-selectors)

So for your example, you'd be doing something like

```
div[class*='text']
```